# What is a better way to access instance variables of base class inside derived class?

Tags: ruby, oop, inheritance

What is a better way to access the base class's instance variables in the derived classes in the case below?

```
class A
   attr_accessor :var_a, :var_b
   def initialize(var_a, var_b)
     @var_a = var_a
     @var_b = var_b
   end
   def xyz
     C.new.xyz
     D.new.xyz
   end
end

class C < A
   def xyz
     puts "C xyz #{var_a} #{var_b}"
   end
end

class D < A
   def xyz
     puts "D xyz #{var_a} #{var_b}"
   end
end

a = A.new
a.xyz
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one, the above won't work because they expect to be initialized with the same number of arguments as the base class.  Secondly, you're creating new instances when you call `C.new.xyz` or `D.new.xyz`, so they're not going to automatically have access to `var_a` or `var_b` of your instance returned by `A.new`.

For this to work, you're going to have to instantiate with `a = A.new('foo', 'bar')`, and then inside of `A#xyz`, you're going to have to instantiate those with `var_a` and `var_b`.

```
def xyz
  C.new(var_a, var_b).xyz
  D.new(var_a, var_b).xyz
end
```

If you're looking for `var_a` and `var_b` to be shared across all instances, you're looking for class variables instead of instance variables.  Those are prefixed with `@@` instead of `@`.